# Can we run Oracle Forms against a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, oracleforms

I want to migrate my Oracle database to MySqlbut the problem is that my front end is in ORACLE FORMS 10G.  I have not been able to find whether I can work with mySQL as backend and Oracle forms as front end ?

If not then what is the reason and possible alternatives?
Thanx in advance

Comment: Please fix your question title. It does not describe the question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently we can configure Oracle Forms to use ODBC.  Never done it myself, but I found [a guide to doing this with MS Access on OraFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/93840/286922/0/#msg_286922).  That should be fairly simple to apply to MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com) Import external data wizard to migrate your Oracle db to MySQL db. It can import data from any ODBC compliant data source to MySQL. Import external data requires an appropriate Oracle ODBC-driver (matching the data source) installed on the system where SQLyog is running. I prefer this wizard as it can import from various ODBC-compliant data source and can also schedule the import/migration to MySQL using [SJA](http://webyog.com/faq/content/27/114/en/introduction-to-the-_sqlyog-job-agent_-sja.html)

Comment: The question is not about migrating the data to MySQL, it is about running Oracle Forms against a different database.